# CSS table not expanding properly -- overlaps other content

Tags: css, wordpress

On the page:
http://sooniwill.be/personality-test/

You can click the "Show results" button to see a table with the test results. But as you'll notice, it bleeds into the footer instead of the webpage creating room for the table.

My stylesheet is here:
http://sooniwill.be/personality/main.css (see result-facets)

I know just enough CSS to get myself in trouble. I've done several web searches for similar issues and tried implementing some CSS to fix it. Every once in a while I'll make an edit that displays it properly, but then I reload the page and it overlaps into the footer again. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why does `#main` have a set height of `1748px;`?

Comment: That would explain a lot. I'm importing this from another site so there might be some old code that's no longer needed. I don't see where this height is set though -- where are you seeing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some javascript that's applying `height: 1723px` to the `#main` div. If you disable that it will fix your problem and the `#main` div will expand to contain the entire table.

**Edit:**
Alternatively, you could add a rule to your CSS to override the height.

### CSS

```
#main {
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: Spotted the same thing too. Not a big fan of using `!important` to override the Javascript setting but great alternative to fixing the Javascript.

Comment: Auto height seems to have worked! Thanks so much. I'll see if I can track down where this other height is coming from as well. I'm guessing it's the result of importing the code from its original page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In [this css document](http://sooniwill.be/wp-content/themes/deliciousmagazine/style.css)

/* Clear Floats  */
.col-full:after{content:".";display:block;height:0;clear:both;visibility:hidden;}

delete the height on this line cause you are adding this class to your `<div id="content">`

`<div id="content" class="page col-full">` at the `255` line on your main document

or try adding a static height

if that does not work add the `css` `overflow: scroll` and a static height

Comment: and to your `<div id="main" class="col-left">` remove the height same for `<div id="sidebar" class="col-right">`

Comment: Thanks, still checking this out but thgaskell's suggestion appears to be working now!